# this.id ajax php, quiero manejar 2 this id diferentes div

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

tengo varios div con id quiero traer los datos de esos id, de momento solo puedo traer un id no se como traer los demas.

manejo 2 archivos uno que es el manejador que contiene las funciones, otro archivo donde tengo funciones y creo una tabla con variables y hay pongo los id para manejarlos en el otro archivo.

donde tengo la tabla y las variables donde las declaro como id.

```
echo '<div class="div_comment">';
                        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp; ;;;&nbsp;'.$ARRAY[$x]['comment'];
                    echo '</div>';
                //  }
                    if ($ARRAY[$x]["disabled"]=="false"){  $clase="class='div_row_child'"; }else{ $clase="class='div_row_child div_row_disabled'"; }

                    echo '<div class="div_row_repeat" id="'.$ARRAY[$x][".id"].''.$ARRAY[$x]["name"].'"  >';

                        echo '<div class="div_row_child div_row_child_img" style="width:10%;">&nbsp;</div>';
                        //echo '<div '. $clase .' style="width:7%;">&nbsp;'.$ARRAY[$x][".id"].'</div>';
                        echo '<div '. $clase .' id="'.$ARRAY[$x]["name"].'" style="width:30%;">&nbsp;'.$ARRAY[$x]["name"].'</div>';
                        echo '<div '. $clase .' style="width:30%;">&nbsp;'.$ipb.'</div>';
                        echo '<div '. $clase .' style="width:15%;">&nbsp;'.$down.'</div>';
                        echo '<div '. $clase .' style="width:15%;">&nbsp;'.$up.'</div>';
                        //echo '<div '. $clase .' style="width:18%;">&nbsp;'.$ARRAY[$x]["type"].'</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
```

aca tengo la funcion this para llamar el id actual pero quiero obtener los dos id.

aclaro que los invoco para ponerlos en un input id=idh que funciona pero quiero el otro input id=name2 con la variable nameb que es del this.name.

```
// cargo la lista de ip-bindings
var ajax_load = "<img src='img/indicator_white_small' alt='loading...' />";
var loadUrl = "hotspot_ip-binding-all.php";
$("#call_bindings").click(function(){
    $("#div_bindings").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
});
$("#div_bindings").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);

// pinta el registro seleccionado y despinta el resto
$("div").on("click", ".div_row_repeat", function() {
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    var id = this.id
  // este id no carga
    var nameb = this.id2
    $(".tabla div.div_row_repeat").children().each(function(index , Elem) {
        if($(Elem).parent().attr('id')==id){
            $(Elem).addClass('highlight');
            $('input[name=idh]').val(id);
 //no carga
    $('input[name=name2]').val(nameb);
        }
    });
});
```

los input asi

```
<input type="text" id="idh" name="idh" value="" />
<input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" value=" " />
```

quiero poner la informacion this.id en los input en uno funciona en el otro no.

asi me funciono

Le puse clases v1, v2 sucesivamente a cada div con los id en archivo 2.php

```
if ($ARRAY[$x]["disabled"]=="false"){  $clase="div_row_child"; }else{ $clase="div_row_child div_row_disabled"; }

                    echo '<div class="div_row_repeat" id="'.$ARRAY[$x][".id"].'"  >';

                        echo '<div class="div_row_child div_row_child_img" style="width:10%;">&nbsp;</div>';
                        //echo '<div '. $clase .' style="width:7%;">&nbsp;'.$ARRAY[$x][".id"].'</div>';
                        echo '<div   class="'. $clase .' v1"   id="'.$ARRAY[$x]["name"].'" style="width:30%;">&nbsp;'.$ARRAY[$x]["name"].'</div>';
                        echo '<div    class="'. $clase .' v2" id="'.$ipb.'" style="width:30%;">&nbsp;'.$ipb.'</div>';
                        echo '<div    class="'. $clase .' v3" id="'.$down.'" style="width:15%;">&nbsp;'.$down.'</div>';
                        echo '<div   class="'. $clase .' v4" id="'.$up.'" style="width:15%;">&nbsp;'.$up.'</div>';
                        //echo '<div '. $clase .' style="width:18%;">&nbsp;'.$ARRAY[$x]["type"].'</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
```

los tome llamando la clase v1, v2 mediante onClick

```
// pinta el registro seleccionado y despinta el resto
$("div").on("click", ".div_row_repeat", function() {
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    var id = this.id;
    $(".tabla div.div_row_repeat").children().each(function(index , Elem) {
        if($(Elem).parent().attr('id')==id){
            $(Elem).addClass('highlight');
            $('input[name=idh]').val(id);

        }
    });
});
$("div").on("click", ".v1", function() {
    var nameb = this.id;
            $('input[name=name2]').val(nameb);


});
$("div").on("click", ".v2", function() {
    var ip3 = this.id;
            $('input[name=ip2]').val(ip3);


});
```

y si me carga los valores en los input

```
<input type="text" id="idh" name="idh" value="" />
<input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" value="" />
<input type="text" id="ip2" name="ip2" value="" />
```

me carga los id en los input, pero solo si doy click en ese div obviamente.
quiero si es posible si al dar click en el div padre carguen toda la info.

para que en input name2 cargue el valor debo dar click en CLT... y para que cargue valor en input ip2 debo dar click encima de 192.168.40..., no como el input idh que carga dando click en cualquier parte de la fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antema gracias por la atencion prestada.

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que en el contexto de tu código `this` sería el elemento sobre el que se hizo click (el `div`), por lo que no tendría ningún sentido esto:

```
var id = this.id;
var id2 = this.id[1];
```

Si ya conoces de antemano los id puedes alcanzarlos directamente.

Veamos un ejemplo con Javascript puro:

```js
var idh=document.getElementById("idh");
var name2=document.getElementById("name2");

console.log(idh.value);
console.log(name2.value);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="idh" name="idh" value="Test1" />
<input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" value="Test2" />
```

Si sólo te interesa el valor, puedes declarar las variables así directamente:

```js
var idh=document.getElementById("idh").value;
var name2=document.getElementById("name2").value;

console.log(idh);
console.log(name2);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="idh" name="idh" value="Test1" />
<input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" value="Test2" />
```

No obstante, en Javascript se recomienda crear una referencia a los elementos y luego usar esa referencia para obtener/modificar sus propiedades, en este caso el `value`, que es la práctica observada en el primer bloque.

Veamos ahora un ejemplo basado en jQuery:

```js
var idh = $("#idh");
var name2 = $("#name2");

console.log(idh.val());
console.log(name2.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="idh" name="idh" value="Test1" />
<input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" value="Test2" />
```

En resumen: dado que el `id` debería ser único por cada elemento, generalmente la selección por id se hace de manera directa, salvo excepciones, como contextos en los que asignaste ids incrementales y por algún motivo quieres alcanzarlos de igual modo.

Comment: Solo para aclarar, el div con el id lo tengo en otro archivo php. Ese es id=. $ARRAY[$x] [. id], el otro id=. $ARRAY[$x] [.name]. Solo carga el primer ID en el input id=idh. Esta var id=this.id. Lo carga al input - $('input[name=idh]').val(id).

Comment: Pero quiero que me cargue en el otro input el contenido del otro div. Que como viste esta dentro del div que ya me funciona.

Comment: Edite la pregunta quite lo que había puesto que comentaste no funcionaba y esta como funciona, carga solo el contenido del div al input idh. Recuerda esta el div en otro archivo php.

Comment: No logro entender lo que me quieres decir, @jhongarcia.

Comment: Creo haces refencia o invocas al id dentro del mismo archivo y el id o ids los tengo en otro archivo php. Logré hacerlo funcionar pero no tomando id sino las clases. A cada div le puse clase diferente. Pero el problema es que solo me carga el valor id en el input si doy click en la clase. No se si hay una que me cargue si le doy click al div padre.

Comment: Es obligatorio que estén en el mismo contexto (no necesariamente el mismo archivo). Por ejemplo, el contenido de una página puede crearse mediante un archivo PHP de un lado y un archivo Javascript de otro lado, pero todo se ensambla constituyendo un único contenido. Me parece que tienes mucha confusión al respecto y por eso no logras aclararte con este problema.

Comment: YA edite la pregunta con lo que acabo de hacer e imagen, trate con lo que me dijiste pero no me funciono, de antemano gracias por la atencion. @a-cedano